# Search same string in line of file

Tags: python, string, file, substring

In a file I have several lines with this structure:

```
> Present one time: "Instance: ...Edition: ..."
> Present two times: "Instance: ...Edition: ...Instance: ...Edition: ..."
> Present n times: "Instance: ...Edition: ... [n] Instance: ...Edition: ..."
```

**This structure can appear once per line or several times on the same line.** The idea is to read the file, line by line, isolate the values represented by *...* and write them in an excel file. I can do it but I'm only able to isolate the values if the structure above is present one time in the line. If the structure is present more than once on the line, I can only save the values ​​of the first structure.
This is my code:

```
#READ FILE
for i in fin:
    if "Instance:" in i:
        instance = ((i.split('Instance:'))[1].split('Edition')[0])
        worksheet.write(row, col, instance)
    if "Edition:" in i:
        edition = ((i.split('Edition:'))[1].split('\n')[0])
        worksheet.write(row, col, edition)
    row += 1
```

Any idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: So you want to remove every "Instance", "Edition:" and "\n" from the string and get the remaining content concatenated?

Comment: Also, if both "Instance" and "Edition" is present, your content following "Edition" will overwrite the content following "Instance", is that what you want?

Comment: What about lines that do not start with "Instance" but do contain "Edition"... is that possible? Right now your code allows it.

Comment: The idea is that if the line looks like this: "Instance: 1 Edition: 2 Instance: 3 Edition: 4", I can isolate 1, 2, 3, 4 but for now with my code I can only isolate the 1 and 2. I hope it was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this only works if your input ends in an empty line (called newline).
If it does not you can add it like so:  `s += '\n'`

```py
s = '''Instance: A Edition: Limited
Instance: B Edition: Common Instance: C Edition: 2020 Instance: D Edition: Bla
'''

result = []
start_in = start_ed = None
for i in range(len(s)):
    # Reaching the end of a data item
    if s[i:i+9] == 'Instance:' or s[i] == '\n':
        if start_in and start_ed:
            result.append(
                (s[start_in:start_ed-8].strip(), s[start_ed:i].strip())
            )
            start_in = start_ed = None

    if s[i:i+9] == 'Instance:':
        start_in = i+9
    if s[i:i+8] == 'Edition:':
        start_ed = i+8

print(result)
```

```
[('A', 'Limited'), ('B', 'Common'), ('C', '2020'), ('D', 'Bla')]
```

---

**Edit:** With `Version` field as requested

```py
s = '''Instance: A Edition: Limited Version: 1
Instance: B Edition: Common Version: 2 Instance: C Edition: 2020 Version: 3 Instance: D Edition: Bla Version: 4
'''

result = []
start_in = start_ed = start_vs = None
for i in range(len(s)):
    # Reaching the end of a data item
    if s[i:i+9] == 'Instance:' or s[i] == '\n':
        if start_in and start_ed and start_vs:
            result.append((
                s[start_in:start_ed-8].strip(),
                s[start_ed:start_vs-8].strip(),
                s[start_vs:i].strip()
            ))
            start_in = start_ed = start_vs = None

    if s[i:i+9] == 'Instance:':
        start_in = i+9
    if s[i:i+8] == 'Edition:':
        start_ed = i+8
    if s[i:i+8] == 'Version:':
        start_vs = i+8

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I prefer this solution because it's easier to understand. Now if the structure had a Version field after the Edition, would the change be to add s[i:i+9] == 'Version:' at the end of the code?

Comment: Is the Version field always present or optional? You would need an additional variable `start_vs` and since the string "Version:" has 8 letters it would be `s[i:i+8] == 'Version:'` with `s[start_ed:start_vs-8]` and `s[start_vs:i]` appended

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll do tests, you've helped me a lot! All the best

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: I'm not getting results if the structure becomes "Instance: ... Edition: ... Version: ...", can you help me please

Comment: Is the version field always present? I can edit my answer

Comment: That would be fantastic! Yes, it's always

Comment: I've added a version with 'Version' (:

Comment: You're a BOSS! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). This is shorter but maybe harder to read and maintain:

```py
import re
r = re.findall(r'Instance:([\w|\s]+?)Edition:([\w|\s]+?)(?=Instance|\n)', s)
```

```
[(' A ', ' Limited'), (' B ', ' Common '), (' C ', ' 2020 '), (' D ', ' Bla')]
```

If you don't want spaces around your matches you can either apply a `strip` to all elements like I did in my other solution, or you can modify the regex to read `Instance: ([\w...`